# How to segue between views horizontally without navigation bar?

Tags: xcode, navigation

I'm currently making a simple app that has 3 views. I would like to be able to move between views using the swipe gesture.

Keep in mind that I'm pretty new to using xcode so my current solution is to: add "swipe gesture" to my first view controller and connect that gesture to the next view using "show" as my segue.

However, "show" makes the transition bottom up while I'd like to make the transition right left.

I've tried embedding my first view into a navigation controller, which allows the transition to be horizontal. I link my first view to my second view using "swipe gesture" and voila, it goes to the second view with a horizontal segue. However, the only way back to the first view is to press the "back" button the navigation bar.

Is there a way to navigate between just a few views using your own gestures/buttons with horizontal transitions?

Answer (score 0):

If segues are not a requirement, it might be possible to use push and pop functions to transition between your views. Set up IBActions to receive the swipe gestures, and have them execute a push or pop depending on which way the user swiped.

```
@IBAction func leftSwipeHandler(_ gestureRecognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
  if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
    let view2 = secondViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
  }
}

@IBAction func rightSwipeHandler(_ gestureRecognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
  if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```